# How to get array of countries or states or cities using google map SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, geocoding, gmsmapview

I need to obtain an array of countries, or states or cities present within a visible bounds on the map view. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: No, this is searching using text box. In my case, I'm trying to get data which is visible in the map view. For example, if the map view is displayed with zoom level of 2, then it shows multiple countries. How do I get those list of countries ?

Comment: You can use the [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete). In its `GMSPlacesClient autocompleteQuery:bounds:filter:callback:` method, you can put a `bounds` parameter in it, you can get the bounds by doing `GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion:[mapView_.projection visibleRegion]];`

Comment: Thanks.... Can you please give an example ?